# Does Postgis ST_FrechetDistance have limitations?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Using ST_FrechetDistance(geom1, geom2) from Postgis will cause my Postgres server to lose connection if the number of points in the geometries is in the thousands(+6k). Is it possible to increase this limitation or bypass it somehow? It works perfectly fine with smaller geometries.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [O(n**2) operation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_FrechetDistance.html). So working with 1000 points will take roughly four times as long as working with 500 points, and 100 times as long as working with 100 points. O(n**2) is a harsh master.

Try setting the `densityFrac` parameter to break up your long geometries.  It's the third parameter to the function. In this example it dedensifies -- breaks up -- your segments into tenths.

```
ST_FrechetDistance(geo1::geometry, geo2::geometry, 0.1);
```

Comment: That makes sense. It does succesfully return now, but there's no output. pgAdmin doesn't give any output unfortunately. As soon as I attempt to do anything with the result of FrechetDistance like a comparison greather than 0 or something for the purpose of testing I get the following error: ERROR:  GEOSFrechetDistance: std::bad_alloc
SQL state: XX000
This is when I run a query on only 2 geometries that are large. I'm not going through any table.